# Selecting resource file with GetGlobalResourceObject, reading against current culture

Tags: .net, asp.net

I'm using GetGlobalResourceObject to localise the language on a website after setting CurrentUICulture depending on each users settings.

I am also creating an email using text retrieved via GetGlobalResourceObject which is sent to another user. Is it possible to select the language file used by GetGlobalResourceObject so that the email is sent in the language of the recipient rather than the sender (which happens by default).

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple once you find the right link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149949.aspx